# Not getting the correct path in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, configuration

I'm trying to copy a jar that I am running into a HDFS location internally in the code like this:

```
MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()
```

If I export the classpath correctly:

```
export $HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/path/to/jar.jar
```

then, I get the correct path from where I am running the jar. However, if I give the name of the jar incorrectly:

```
export $HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/path/to/jar1.jar
```

then, it takes the path to the tmp folder where it is unjaring the jar before the run.

Can anyone help me in understanding why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: does it also store all the files parked along with the correct path [/path/to/jar.jar] ?

Comment: There are no other files. This is the only file the rest is created during the hadoop job run.

Comment: So try adding other files in [/path/to/] and give the correct path [/path/to/jar.jar] and see if that file also get persisted

Comment: the question is not whether I'm giving the correct path or not. The question is why is taking the path of the temp directory where it is being unjared